# ArrayList is not properly printing User's inputs (ArrayList of a Class)

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I've been tasked to create a practice database for a programming assignment.

It consists of asking the user for the data of a Course such as: the Instructor name, the section number, and the room number.

Then I ask the user for information about a student: the student's name, his gpa, his major, and his hours.

After getting the information for the Course, I must create an ArrayList of the Student class, and allow the user to input multiple students. So a basic prompt would go as such:

```
 Please enter the section number (1 to 15)
 5
 Please enter the instructor for this section
 Frankie
 Please enter the room number.
 A1230
 Please enter a name. Press enter to quit
 Tyler
 Please enter a major
 Frank
 Please enter a grade point average
 3.34
 Please enter the hours
 13
 Please enter a name. Press enter to quit

 5    Frankie   A1230 
 Tyler  13  3.34  Frank
```

The sentinel to exit the loop asking for student information exits once the user inputs enter into the name prompt, then the information is printed below.

My problem is when the user tries to add more than one student into the ArrayList. Here's an example of what happens:

```
Please enter the section number (1 to 15)
4
Please enter the instructor for this section
Jimmie
Please enter the room number.
B1230
Please enter a name. Press enter to quit
Adam
Please enter a major
ITSD
Please enter a grade point average
3.45
Please enter the hours
5
Please enter a name. Press enter to quit
Tonny
Please enter a major
Business
Please enter a grade point average
3.64
Please enter the hours
13
Please enter a name. Press enter to quit

4   Jimmie  B1230 
Tonny  13  3.64  Business
Tonny  13  3.64  Business
```

The correct output should be:

```
Tonny 13  3.64  Business
Adam  5   3.45  ITSD
```

It seems that when I add the student inputs into my ArrayList, **the previous values of the inputs are overwritten with the new values the user enters for the next Student**. I'm thinking that there's something wrong with my toString() method in my Student class. Here are my three classes: I have a Driver (Tester), Student (validates inputs for student info), and Course (validates inputs for course info and returns a toString which is printed in the Driver main method).

**Driver Class** 
- Holds the main method, asks the user to input information for the prompts, it then adds the inputs for the Student information into the getAdd method in the Course method

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Driver 
{
      Student stud = new Student();
    Course cour2 = new Course();


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Driver driv = new Driver();

        driv.getCourseInfo();

        boolean another;
        do
        {
        another = driv.getStudentInfo();

        }while(another);
        System.out.println(driv.cour2.toString());
    }

    public void getCourseInfo()
    {
        int sectionValid = 0;
        int instructorValid = 0;
        int roomValid = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Please enter the section number (1 to 15)");
        sectionValid = cour2.setSectionNumber(input.nextInt());
        while(!(sectionValid == 1))
        {   

                System.out.println("Your input was invalid. Please enter the section number (1 to 15)");
                sectionValid = cour2.setSectionNumber(input.nextInt());
        }


        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the instructor for this section");
        instructorValid = cour2.setInstructor(input.nextLine());

        while (instructorValid == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Your input cannot be blank. Please enter an instructor.");
            instructorValid = cour2.setInstructor(input.nextLine());
        }


        System.out.println("Please enter the room number.");
        roomValid = cour2.setRoom(input.nextLine());

        while (roomValid == 0)
        {
                System.out.println("The room number cannot be blank. Please enter a room number.");
                roomValid = cour2.setRoom(input.nextLine());
        }
    }



    public boolean getStudentInfo()
    {
        boolean another = true;
        int nameValid = 0;
        int majorValid = 0;
        int gradePointAverageValid = 0;
        int hoursValid = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Please enter a name. Press enter to quit");
        nameValid = stud.setName(input.nextLine());

        if (nameValid == 1)
        {

            another = true;
            System.out.println("Please enter a major");
            majorValid = stud.setMajor(input.nextLine());


            while (majorValid == 0)
            {
                    System.out.println("The major cannot be blank. Please enter a major");
                    majorValid = stud.setMajor(input.nextLine());
            }


            System.out.println("Please enter a grade point average");
            gradePointAverageValid = stud.setGradePointAverage(input.nextDouble());

            while (gradePointAverageValid == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("The grade point average has to be between 0.00 and 4.00. Please enter a grade point average");
                gradePointAverageValid = stud.setGradePointAverage(input.nextDouble());
            }


            System.out.println("Please enter the hours");
            hoursValid = stud.setHours(input.nextInt());

            while (hoursValid == 0)
            {
                    System.out.println("Hours cannot be greater than 17. Please enter the hours");
                    hoursValid = stud.setHours(input.nextInt());
            }


            cour2.addStudent(stud);
        }
        else
        {
            another = false;
        }
          return another;

    }
    }
```

**The Student Class:** Holds validations for the inputs for student information and has a toString() method that returns the sectionNumber, room, etc. variables. This toString() is then called in the Course class to be printed for each instance of the ArrayList students. **I believe this to be the area where I have a problem (toString())**

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Course 
{
 private int sectionNumber;
 private String instructor;
 private String room;
 private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
 Student studs = new Student();



 public int getSectionNumber()
 {
  return sectionNumber;
 }

 public int setSectionNumber(int sectionNumber)
 {
  int sectionValid = 0;

  if (sectionNumber >= 1 && sectionNumber <= 15)
  {
   this.sectionNumber = sectionNumber;
   sectionValid = 1;
  }
  return sectionValid;
 }

 public String getInstructor()
 {
  return instructor;
 }

 public int setInstructor(String instructor)
 {
  int instructorValid = 0;

  if (instructor.length() != 0)
  {
   this.instructor = instructor;
   instructorValid = 1;
  }
  return instructorValid;
 }

 public String getRoom()
 {
  return room;
 }

 public int setRoom(String room)
 {
  int roomValid = 0;

  if (room.length() != 0)
  {
   this.room = room;
   roomValid = 1;
  }
  return roomValid;
 }


    public void addStudent(Student stud)
    {
     students.add(stud);
    }



    public String toString()
    {
    String results = " ";
        for (Student s  : students)
    {
     results += "\n" + s.toString();
    }

    return this.sectionNumber + "\t" + this.instructor + "\t" + this.room + results;
    }
  }
```

And now finally, **The Course Class:** This holds similar properties to the Student class, it contains validations for the user inputs for the Course information, but it contains the ArrayList students variable (which is causing me problems). The toString() method within this class is called from the driver class, **so this toString() method is the one being printed back to the user.** I believe I correctly use the forreach loop to add the student inputs to a String, and then return that string to be printed. I believe this might be wrong too.. But I'm not too sure.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Course 
{
 private int sectionNumber;
 private String instructor;
 private String room;
 private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
 Student studs = new Student();



 public int getSectionNumber()
 {
  return sectionNumber;
 }

 public int setSectionNumber(int sectionNumber)
 {
  int sectionValid = 0;

  if (sectionNumber >= 1 && sectionNumber <= 15)
  {
   this.sectionNumber = sectionNumber;
   sectionValid = 1;
  }
  return sectionValid;
 }

 public String getInstructor()
 {
  return instructor;
 }

 public int setInstructor(String instructor)
 {
  int instructorValid = 0;

  if (instructor.length() != 0)
  {
   this.instructor = instructor;
   instructorValid = 1;
  }
  return instructorValid;
 }

 public String getRoom()
 {
  return room;
 }

 public int setRoom(String room)
 {
  int roomValid = 0;

  if (room.length() != 0)
  {
   this.room = room;
   roomValid = 1;
  }
  return roomValid;
 }


    public void addStudent(Student stud)
    {
     students.add(stud);
    }



    public String toString()
    {
    String results = " ";
        for (Student s  : students)
    {
     results += "\n" + s.toString();
    }

    return this.sectionNumber + "\t" + this.instructor + "\t" + this.room + results;
    }





}
```

Sorry for the overload of information, I just wanted to present the full scope of the problem to so you all could see what was happening to everything. I'm still a novice in java programming, but I'm trying my best to learn. Any tips or advice is appreciated! This is already past due, so my grade has already suffered, I'd honestly just like to learn what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks! Please comment if you have any question regarding the scope, I tried to explain the problem well and show you a sample output.

To summarize:

I don't understand why my ArrayList is printing the final student information entered, rather than printing each individual student information (if that makes sense).

Please note: I have validated that this program does run and print out inputs, so if you try to copy and paste it into your own eclipse and there are errors, it might be from a copy-paste error that I've made from my own code, or some other compiler specific jargon.

Comment: You posted the `Course` class twice instead of the `Student` class. Also **please** indent your code.

Comment: Besides - it might be less work to run this in a debugger; compared to put up such a huge question. One hint on your code: use a **StringBuilder** when building strings in a loop. What you wrote there is like the least desirable way to concatenate strings.

Comment: Also, what [Tim B](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3049628/tim-b) says.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pasted the Course class, I was in a hurry to get to class. And thanks for the advice Jagermeister!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't copied the students class... But the solution is:

The Problem is not that the ArrayList prints false. The problem is that you use the objects wrong...

You should create new objects of Student if you create a new student. And also create new object of course. If you just change the variables in one class you override your first input...

just add this to getCourseInfo: `cour2 = new Course();` and this to getStudentInfo: `stud = new Student();`

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Driver 
{
  Student stud = new Student();
Course cour2 = new Course();


public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    Driver driv = new Driver();

    driv.getCourseInfo();

    boolean another;
    do
    {
    another = driv.getStudentInfo();

    }while(another);
    System.out.println(driv.cour2.toString());
}

public void getCourseInfo()
{
    int sectionValid = 0;
    int instructorValid = 0;
    int roomValid = 0;
    cour2 = new Course();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please enter the section number (1 to 15)");
    sectionValid = cour2.setSectionNumber(input.nextInt());
    while(!(sectionValid == 1))
    {   

            System.out.println("Your input was invalid. Please enter the section number (1 to 15)");
            sectionValid = cour2.setSectionNumber(input.nextInt());
    }


    input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the instructor for this section");
    instructorValid = cour2.setInstructor(input.nextLine());

    while (instructorValid == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Your input cannot be blank. Please enter an instructor.");
        instructorValid = cour2.setInstructor(input.nextLine());
    }


    System.out.println("Please enter the room number.");
    roomValid = cour2.setRoom(input.nextLine());

    while (roomValid == 0)
    {
            System.out.println("The room number cannot be blank. Please enter a room number.");
            roomValid = cour2.setRoom(input.nextLine());
    }
}



public boolean getStudentInfo()
{
    boolean another = true;
    int nameValid = 0;
    int majorValid = 0;
    int gradePointAverageValid = 0;
    int hoursValid = 0;
    stud = new Student();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please enter a name. Press enter to quit");
    nameValid = stud.setName(input.nextLine());

    if (nameValid == 1)
    {

        another = true;
        System.out.println("Please enter a major");
        majorValid = stud.setMajor(input.nextLine());


        while (majorValid == 0)
        {
                System.out.println("The major cannot be blank. Please enter a major");
                majorValid = stud.setMajor(input.nextLine());
        }


        System.out.println("Please enter a grade point average");
        gradePointAverageValid = stud.setGradePointAverage(input.nextDouble());

        while (gradePointAverageValid == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("The grade point average has to be between 0.00 and 4.00. Please enter a grade point average");
            gradePointAverageValid = stud.setGradePointAverage(input.nextDouble());
        }


        System.out.println("Please enter the hours");
        hoursValid = stud.setHours(input.nextInt());

        while (hoursValid == 0)
        {
                System.out.println("Hours cannot be greater than 17. Please enter the hours");
                hoursValid = stud.setHours(input.nextInt());
        }


        cour2.addStudent(stud);
    }
    else
    {
        another = false;
    }
      return another;

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've not studied the code in detail but I only see one place you are creating a `new Student`. If you create one `Student` object then repeatedly set and reset the values inside that then it will give you the symptoms you are describing.

Note that you can add the same object multiple times to one list.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave a clue.

- Change your `getStudentInfo()` method to return populated `Student` object.
- Similairly `getCourseInfo()` should return populated `Course` object.